# insert multiple row codeigniter with 1 field

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have view questioner, I want to insert multiple row (jawaban and soal), see below

**My View**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td><input type="hidden" value="1" name="no_soal[]">apakah anda sehat</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="-5" name="jawaban[]"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="-3" name="jawaban[]"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="-1" name="jawaban[]"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="0" name="jawaban[]"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="jawaban[]"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="3" name="jawaban[]"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="5" name="jawaban[]"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>10</td>
        <td><input type="hidden" value="2" name="no_soal[]">apakah anda rajin mandi</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="-5" name="jawaban[]"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="-3" name="jawaban[]"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="-1" name="jawaban[]"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="0" name="jawaban[]"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="jawaban[]"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="3" name="jawaban[]"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="5" name="jawaban[]"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" class="submit btn btn-success" value="Submit"/>
```

**My Controller**

```
public function add_soal4()
{
    $id= $this->session->userdata('id');
    $userid= $this->session->userdata('id');
    $data = array();
    if ($_POST)
    {
        $i = 0;
        $no_soal = $this->input->post("no_soal");
        $jawaban = $this->input->post("jawaban");
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($this->input->post('id')); $i++)
        {
            $data[] = array(
                'id' => $id,
                'userid' => $userid,
                'no_soal' => $no_soal[$i],
                'jawaban' => $jawaban[$i]
            );
        }
        $this->db->insert_batch('data_jawaban', $data);
    }
}
```

Now I can insert only 1 record, I need to insert all selected field to the database as multiple value

Comment: just add $data = array(); above for loop and check

Comment: is $this->input->post('id') an array?

Comment: @prasannaputtaswamy 
how, if the "soal"  is 100

Comment: if the "no_soal" is 100 you will have 100 rows right. in that it works fine

Comment: @Mukhammad Arifin, check my answer, I'm pretty sure i will works 100%, i have tested too

Comment: thanks @AnfathHifans...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to use `add_soal4` for php submit and ajax call, so we should do small modification in the `add_soal4` function

**In Controller** in *add_soal4()*

```
public function add_soal4(){
    $id = $this->session->userdata('id');
    $userid = $this->session->userdata('id');        
    if($this->input->post() && !empty($id) && !empty($userid)){         
        $no_soal_list = $this->input->post("no_soal");
        $jawaban_list = $this->input->post("jawaban");
        if($jawaban_list && array_filter($jawaban_list)){
            $answer_list = [];
            foreach($jawaban_list as $no_soal => $jawaban_row){
                foreach($jawaban_row as $jawaban){
                    $answer_list[] = compact('id','userid','no_soal','jawaban');
                }                    
            }
            if(array_filter($answer_list)){
                $this->db->delete('data_jawaban', compact('id','userid'));
                $this->db->insert_batch('data_jawaban', $answer_list);
                echo ($this->db->trans_status()) ? 'Updated' : 'Failed';
            }
        }
    }
    if(!$this->input->is_ajax_request()){
        // if you have any $this->load->view() file, call it here, dont call the view files outside the loop
    }
}
```

add this code in your view file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var autoinsert = setInterval(autosave, 10000); // 10 seconds
    $('form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        clearInterval(autoinsert);
        e.target.submit();
    });
});
function autosave(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<?= base_url('online/add_soal4'); ?>',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data){
            if(data){
                console.log($.parseHTML(data)[0].textContent);
            }            
        },
        error: function(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Note : do not add 10 sec , its too quick, every 10 sec your code will send request to the server. so your server will be slow. so keep minimum 1 minute delay

Comment: this script runs but the resulting data becomes a lot

Comment: yeah you are inserting the values to the database every 10 seconds. so everything request your data will be store in database, that's why too much data... do do auto insert. just make it as before if user submit only submit the form..

Comment: i want : so when "autosave" no_soal and insert answer to the database and when the submit update only (if there are "jawaban" that are replaced)

Comment: @MukhammadArifin, i have updated the answer. try now. i'm sure i will work

Comment: I want view data serialize from database, i put <td><input type="checkbox" value="5" name="jawaban[1][]"><? if (data['no_soal']=="1"; data['jawaban']=="5"){echo 'checked="checked"';}?></td>? how is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Put the `insert` line inside `for` loop.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($this->input->post('id')); $i++) {
     $data = array(
         'id' => $id,
         'userid' => $userid,
          'no_soal' => $no_soal[$i],
          'jawaban' => $jawaban[$i]);
          $this->db->insert_batch('data_jawaban', $data);
  }
```

Comment: `$this->db->insert_batch('data_jawaban', $data);` inside the loop?

Answer (score 0):

You should replace your `HTML` format as like below

**In View**

```
<?=form_open();?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td><input type="hidden" value="1" name="no_soal[1]">apakah anda sehat</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="-5" name="jawaban[1][]"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="-3" name="jawaban[1][]"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="-1" name="jawaban[1][]"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="0" name="jawaban[1][]"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="jawaban[1][]"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="3" name="jawaban[1][]"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="5" name="jawaban[1][]"></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>10</td>
        <td><input type="hidden" value="2" name="no_soal[2]">apakah anda rajin mandi</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="-5" name="jawaban[2][]"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="-3" name="jawaban[2][]"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="-1" name="jawaban[2][]"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="0" name="jawaban[2][]"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="jawaban[2][]"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="3" name="jawaban[2][]"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="5" name="jawaban[2][]"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" class="submit btn btn-success" value="Submit"/>
<?=  form_close();?>
```

replace your function by following codes

**In Controller**

```
public function add_soal4(){
    $id = $this->session->userdata('id');
    $userid = $this->session->userdata('id');        
    if($this->input->post() && !empty($id) && !empty($userid)){ 
        $no_soal_list = $this->input->post("no_soal");
        $jawaban_list = $this->input->post("jawaban");
        if(array_filter($jawaban_list)){
            $answer_list = [];
            foreach($jawaban_list as $no_soal => $jawaban_row){
                foreach($jawaban_row as $jawaban){
                    $answer_list[] = compact('id','userid','no_soal','jawaban');
                }                    
            }
            if(array_filter($answer_list)){
                $this->db->insert_batch('data_jawaban', $answer_list);
                echo ($this->db->trans_status()) ? 'Updated' : 'Failed';
            }
        }
    }        
}
```

Comment: hello @Anfath Hifans, in "view" I add the auto insert script interval 10 seconds, but can not run. see below

Answer (score 0):

in "view" I add the auto insert script interval 10 seconds, but can not run. Here is my script code

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){ autosave(); });
      function autosave(){
        var t = setTimeout("autosave()", 10000);
        var id = $("#id").val();
        var no_soal = $(this).find('input[name=no_soal]').eq(index).val();
        var jawaban = $(this).find('input[name=jawaban]').eq(index).val();
           $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url:"<?php echo base_url('online/add_soal4'); ?>",
              dataType : "JSON",
              data : {'id':id, 'no_soal':no_soal,'jawaban':jawaban}, 
              cache: false,
      }
           });  
      } 
  </script>
```

Comment: i have no problems with your script, but I want to add autosave script

Comment: wait im checking

Comment: are you calling any view file inside the `add_soal4` function ?

Comment: im asking you,  are you calling `add_soal4` as like i have added in the anwser right.

Comment: check now i have added the answer